# unable to determine zookeeper ensemble health

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase, cloudera, apache-zookeeper

I setup a 3 node Zookeeper cdh4 ensemble on RHEL 5.5 machines. I have started the service by running `zkServer.sh` on each of the nodes. ZooKeeper instance is running on all the nodes, but how do I know if it is a part of an ensemble or are they running as individual services?

I tried to start the service and check the ensemble as stated [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/zookeeper/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup), on Cloudera's site, but it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the stat [four letter word](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands),

```
~$echo stat | nc 127.0.0.1 <zkport>
```

Which gives you output like,

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
Clients:
 /127.0.0.1:55829[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/0
Received: 3
Sent: 2
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x100000000
Mode: leader
Node count: 4
```

The `Mode:` line tells you what mode the server is running in, either leader, follower or standalone if the node is not part of a cluster.

Comment: Thank you @sbridges! And what does node count actually mean ? Since i setup a 3 node cluster while it shows node count as 4. Also, the way it should be statred, as stated on the link throws an exception. Do you have an idea where i might be going wrong?

Comment: I think node count is the number of znodes.  For the ClassNotFoundException, the class you are trying to run is not on the classpath, as specified with the -cp switch to java.